# Controller functions are not executing Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Controller functions are not executing Angular.

'use strict';

```
angular.module('newproejctApp')
  .controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, User, Auth,dataService) {

      $scope.test="this is not working";

       });


<div class="container" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">

 {{test}}

 </div>
```

The above sample for some reason will not work. The project is produced by Yeoman, and all other controllers are functioning normally.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JS console?  Are you sure that "newproejctApp" isn't a typo?  If you set a breakpoint, does it ever hit the line where you set $scope.test?

Comment: no errors in js console, alert("something"), console.log not working. Do not know how to debug this, it first occured when i tried to inherit  some variable to a child Ctrl and commenting out everything i realized that even the above example is not working @jadarnel27

Comment: Is the above "newproejctApp" supposed to be "newprojectApp"?

Comment: no, and if your module name disagrees with your rest of the project Angular is kind enouph to inform you about this, i get no errors. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass in the empty array in your module definition:

```
angular.module('newproejctApp', [])
```